# Remove jQuery custom event binding

Tags: jquery, events, unbind

I've got some code that closes a custom lightbox when the escape key is pressed. I've tried to write it to unbind the `keyup` event once the escape key has been pressed, but it's not unbinding.

```
        $(document).on('keyup.cookieLaw', function(ev){
            if(ev.keyCode == 27) {
                $(document).off('keyup.cookieLaw');
                methods.toggleInfo(ev);
            }
        });
```

I can't use `one` in place of `on` as that will stop after *any* key is pressed - I need to wait for the escape key.

Any/all help much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried simple `$(document).off('keyup.cookieLaw');` without handler?

Comment: @VisioN yes, sorry i posted the wrong bit of code - that was my first attempt.

Comment: Is the `if (keyCode == 27)` condition actually being hit?

Comment: *Just* that snippet works fine on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kwpuT/ Could there be something else going on?